# Error in PyroCMS 1.3 blog addon

Tags: php, pyrocms

I'm trying to use pyrocms blog addon for a simple news section.

When I access to site.dev/blog this WARNING is displayed:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL in <="" a=""> on line 22
```

**Call Stack**

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  361808  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   0.0017  417440  require_once( '/Users/ignacio/Projects/fidae/system/codeigniter/core/CodeIgniter.php' ) ../index.php:287
3   0.1563  6059080 call_user_func_array ( )    ../CodeIgniter.php:339
4   0.1563  6059124 Blog->index( )  ../CodeIgniter.php:0
5   0.1635  6173280 Template->build( )  ../blog.php:31
6   0.1684  6348004 Template->_load_view( ) ../Template.php:258
7   0.1687  6350256 MY_Parser->parse_string( )  ../Template.php:752
8   0.1687  6350284 MY_Parser->_parse( )    ../MY_Parser.php:59
9   0.1688  6351272 Tags->parse( )  ../MY_Parser.php:92
10  0.1785  6486620 call_user_func ( )  ../Tags.php:255
11  0.1785  6486636 MY_Parser->parser_callback( )   ../Tags.php:0
12  0.1785  6486636 Plugins->locate( )  ../MY_Parser.php:120
13  0.1785  6487112 Plugins->_process( )    ../Plugins.php:144
14  0.1786  6487468 Plugin_Theme->partial( )    ../Plugins.php:223
15  0.1788  6489688 MY_Parser->parse_string( )  ../theme.php:52
16  0.1788  6489688 MY_Parser->_parse( )    ../MY_Parser.php:59
17  0.1789  6490676 Tags->parse( )  ../MY_Parser.php:92
18  0.1861  6540320 Tags->parse_php( )  ../Tags.php:274
```

The "line 22" is a link to txmt://open?url=file:///Users/ignacio/Projects/fid_app/system/cms/libraries/Tags‌​.php(627)%20:%20eval()

**However**.. posts are displayed correctly on page, but the rest of the page is not rendered.

I've tried to hack into the core but everything looks good to me. Any clues?

Comment: Well.. the thing is, I don't know what file this is referencing. The "line 22" is a link to txmt://open?url=file:///Users/ignacio/Projects/fid_app/system/cms/libraries/Tags.php(627)%20:%20eval() :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-posted this in pyro's forums, you can see the complete thread here:http://pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/3848

Basically the problem was a syntax error:

Looking closely at the code you can see that there should be quotes around {pyro:page:is_home}.

So, the correct code is:

```
{if '{pyro:page:is_home}' == TRUE}
{pyro:theme:js file="home.js"}
{/if}
```